# Copying files into a virtual PC is very slow

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a winXP virtual PC running on a powerful win7 x64 (4 cores 8Gb RAM) workstation.
When I'm copying files in the virtual PC, from my workstation `(\\<my computer name>\c$\etc.)`
to the virtual, it goes **extremely** slow even for a 500kb file.
I can, on the other hand, copy (in or out) a 10mb file to a network resource in just a few seconds.

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: What procedure(s) are you using to copy the files?

Comment: Are the virtual machine and the host sharing the same hard drive?

Comment: They are sharing the same hard drive. I'm just using drag and drop of files